# Smoothly toggle transform rotate arrow with bootstrap accordion

Tags: css

I'm using Bootstrap accordion. I have a `img` that change when the button class has `collapsed` class, rotating `180 deg` or `0 deg` if the class isn't active. It's work but I want to make it smoothly, like `keyframes animation`. You can see live example [here](https://lagaleramagazine.es/rucab/habitaciones.html).

```css
.tab-arrow {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.collapsed .tab-arrow {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="card no-focus-outline">
  <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        <div class="card-header bg-rosa mb-5" id="headingOne">
            <div style="max-width: 511px;">
              <h1>HABITACIÓN INDIVIDUAL</h1><img src="https://lagaleramagazine.es/rucab/img/arrow-down.png" class="tab-arrow" style="margin-bottom: -300px; width: 70px; " /></div>   
        </div>
            </button>

  <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/habitaciones/icons/SOL-02-02.png" /></div>
        <div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/habitaciones/icons/VENTILADOR-02.png" /></div>
        <div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/habitaciones/icons/CALEFACCION-02.png" /></div>
        <div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/habitaciones/icons/WIFI-02.png" /></div>
        <div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/habitaciones/icons/ESCRITORIO-02.png" /></div>
        <div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/habitaciones/icons/WC-02.png" /></div>
        <div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/habitaciones/icons/DUCHA-02.png" /></div>
        <div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/habitaciones/icons/TARJETA-02.png" /></div>
        <div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/habitaciones/icons/LIMPIEZA-02.png" /></div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 150px;">
          <div class="img-container-hab col-lg-8 mx-auto">
            <img class="top fade-in" alt=" " src="img/stock-photo-double-bed-in-the-hotel-696169024.jpg" width="100%">

          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 mx-auto home-text-div">
            <p class="habitaciones-text-p text-justify">Habitación totalmente reformada con una cama individual de 0.90 cm, cuenta con calefacción en invierno y ventilador de techo en verano, amplio escritorio y muy luminoso, baño privado dentro de la habitación, agua caliente, un gran armario
              con capacidad para todo lo que necesites guardar, puerta de seguridad con tarjeta de acceso, internet por cable, wifi, una ventana, servicio de limpieza una vez a la semana y un pequeño kit de limpieza para necesidades puntuales. </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
      on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw
      denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add transition to your `.tab-arrow` class.

```css
.tab-arrow {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);

  -webkit-transition: transform 0.25s ease;
    -o-transition: transform 0.25s ease;
    transition: transform 0.25s ease;
}
```

Change 0.25s to whatever value you want to control speed.